# Php file can't insert data to table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need support please, my PHP file can't insert post data from a form to SQL,
but when I use constant values instead of `$_POST['name']` it works.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "hostingo_usrproj";
$password = "basel1990!";
$dbname = "hostingo_project";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$name         =$_POST['name'];
$email        =$_POST{'email'];
$usrpassword  =$_POST['usrpassword'];
$mobile       =$_POST['mobile'];



$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (name, email, usrpassword, mobile )
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$usrpassword', '$mobile')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Enable error_reporting, fix the syntax issues, and investigate prepared statements / parameter binding.

Comment: could we see the html for this mate? did ye get any errors also and what were they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$email        =$_POST{'email'];
```

as per my thinking here is the issue
try this

```
$email        =$_POST['email'];
```